# Fetch the latitude and longitude from the json in PHP . tried solutions which are not working

Tags: php, json, google-maps

The contents of XML data from where the latitude and longitude is to be fetched :-

```
<GetGPSRawDataResponse xmlns="http://xxxx.org/"><GetGPSRawDataResult>[{"IMIENO":"3xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Lattitude":25.4286285,"Longitude":75.0507245,"Altitude":0.000,"Speed":0.000,"CTime":"Jul  8 2015  7:24:02:000PM","RecordTime":"Jul  9 2015  8:46AM","DevDistance":0.1000,"CardID":""},{"IMIENO":"3xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Lattitude":25.4286285,"Longitude":75.0507245,"Altitude":0.000,"Speed":0.000,"CTime":"Jul  8 2015  7:19:02:000PM","RecordTime":"Jul  9 2015  8:49AM","DevDistance":0.0950,"CardID":""}]</GetGPSRawDataResult></GetGPSRawDataResponse>
```

$json=$xmlObj->GetGPSRawDataResult;
//This returns :-

```
[{"IMIENO":"3xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Latitude":25.4286285,"Longitude":75.0507245,"Altitude":0.000,"Speed":0.000,"CTime":"Feb  8 2015  7:24:02:000PM","RecordTime":"Feb  9 2015  8:46AM","DevDistance":0.1000,"CardID":""},{"IMIENO":"3xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Latitude":25.4286285,"Longitude":75.0507245,"Altitude":0.000,"Speed":0.000,"CTime":"Feb  8 2015  7:19:02:000PM","RecordTime":"Feb  9 2015  8:49AM","DevDistance":0.0950,"CardID":""}]
```

Then I did :-

```
$json_decode=json_decode($json);
```

But please help me fetch the latitude and longitude using json. I am not able to retrieve their value. Please help me somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the code below ?

`foreach($json_decode as $row){
    echo $row->Latitude
    echo $row->Longitude
}`

If it doesn't works, please post a var_dump from you `$json_encode variable`

Comment: You are great sir. I was working on this for last 2 days. But wasnt able to find a solution,But u got it in a easy way for me.Really thankful to you.